# IPhone P2P - Problem with p2p connection when 3 iphones are searching

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, p2p

Here's the situation, I made a game that use GKSessionModePeer to do the multiplay mode, but the problem is happened when I use three iphones, just call them A,B,C
when A and C searched B,they choose B at the same time, then the screen change to the waiting for apply page, 
at this moment,problem happen!!!!!
A and C start the game suddenly with no connection from each other ,B's screen show "Do you accept the connection" page, after a second A and C lost connection, what's happen???

I want iphone would accept connection one by one, A and C will not start the game suddenly,
what should i do???

Can anyone help me???

Answer (score 0):

According to the GameKit framework reference:

> Game Kit offers your applications the ability to create Bluetooth connections between two devices.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/GameKit_Collection.pdf

Using GameKit to setup a game for more than 2 players won't work. You'll need to use another solution, such as one of the devices hosting a server and using a wifi network.